# OpenCart auto complete broken on featured module

Tags: module, autocomplete, opencart

apologies if this has already been covered.
I have an issue where i can't add products to the featured module as the auto-complete doesn't find anything and never drops down. Is this something that's happened for any one else?

Currently using v1.5.6

Error shown in console after any action on the featured module admin page is...

*"event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. "*

OpenCarts error log shows...

*'PHP Notice: Undefined variable: filter_category in /home/sites/cardboutique.ie/public_html/admin/controller/catalog/product.php on line 1434'*

I've re-upped all the files (as it was working) but no joy.
I also doubt the first error is the main issue but don't have decent enough knowledge to vouch for that.

Comment: Is this comming from the default OpenCart installation? Sounds more like an old third party extension to me... Anyway, just tested the basic 1.5.6 installation and the default *Featured* module (backend part) with it's autocomplete is working fine for me...

Comment: Have you installed any extension before this error appeared for the first time?